# Looking for jquery database search and retrieve solution

Tags: jquery, database, callback, jquery-callback

I'm a complete noob, but I'm looking to find a solution to pass onto my developers that does something like this:

http://www.madonnacrusaders.com/hallOfFame.php

OR

http://www.yoteathletics.com/hof.aspx?&tab=0

Basically fill a database with specific attributes (awards, years, sport) and have a specific html biography called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

~ Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These websites doesn't use jquery to request their database, but rather, use the [php language](http://php.net/). So, I think you will have to learn how to request a database with this language, using PDO (begining with [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.connections.php) and, after, [this](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)) or mysql (begining with [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) and, after, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)).

Comment: Lucas, thanks for the info. So you're telling me there's no jquery out of the box solution for this? Again, I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: It's not important. We can't know everything... And it's a good thing if you want to know how a website is working. Just, if my answer could help you, you can validate it.

Comment: Is there an out of the box PHP solution you advocate to achieve what is going on in the links in the original question?

Comment: We can't know because we can't see the php code which generate the page you are seeing. The only thing to do is to learn the php language  with pages I sent to you. And just a question, why do you unvalidate my answer ? I took time to answer to your question and I was the only one...

Comment: Thank you to revalidate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a client-side solution, and can be used to process the data and create nice visualizations and animations once the data has been supplied by the server. It cannot make database calls.

Your database will reside somewhere on your back-end, and you can query it using whatever language your server is running. You linked to both a php page and an asp.net page, so it sounds like you might not be sure what the application is currently running. If you have a specific question about how to query a database in one of these languages, ask it as a separate question, and be as detailed as possible about what specifically you are trying to do, and in which language.

Once you get the requested records, you can serialize the results as JSON and pass it to the client for processing/rendering. If you're simply rendering tables/lists you can manually parse the object with JavaScript, or use a jQuery plugin to do layout. You can use CSS for formatting at this point.